# VBA code won't work if at least one of the cells is not below 2 characters

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code,

I use it to transpose a list of numbers and then separate them with a comma,
It works well for every list, if numbers are between 0 and 99.

However if the list of numbers contains numbers with more than 2 characters, then, the code will give the attended result, only if at least one number in the list has 2 characters or less.

If I have a list of numbers with > 2 characters, then it will give me the transposed number without the comma separator.

Could you please advise

```
Option Explicit
Sub colonne_a_ligne()

'On compte le nombre de Trades
Dim Number_of_Trade As Integer
Number_of_Trade = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Dim m As Integer
m = Number_of_Trade + 1

'On transpose les trades en ligne
  Dim sourceRange As Range
  Dim targetRange As Range


  Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Number_of_Trade, 1))
  Set targetRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)

  sourceRange.Copy
  targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

'On met en forme dans le format 
   Dim sisk As String
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long

    For row = 2 To 2
        sisk = vbNullString
        For col = 2 To m
            If VBA.Len(sisk) Then sisk = sisk & ","
            sisk = sisk & Cells(row, col)
        Next col

        Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(3, 2) = sisk

    Next row

End Sub
```

[image: Case 1]

[image: Case 2]

[image: Case 3]

Comment: Can you post some example data, and the output yo get, and the output you want to get?

Comment: I added pictures, I want the column to become a line with values separated by a comma, but it works only if at least one number has 2 characters or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a number formatting issue; specifically with the thousands separator. The second image is showing a true number with a space as the thousands separator but rounded off to 15 digit precision.

This should resolve the attempted auto-conversion to a number.

```
Dim sisk As String
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long

For row = 2 To 2
    sisk = vbNullString
    For col = 2 To m
        sisk = sisk & "," & Cells(row, col).TEXT
    Next col

    Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(3, 2).NUMBERFORMAT = "@"
    Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(3, 2) = MID(sisk, 2)

Next row
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot I would have never found, how did you do to know this

Comment: I couldn't figure it out until you posted images. All those zeroes were the clue that the result was being treated as a true number (15 digit precision). After I realized that, I just applied more text-direct methods so Excel wouldn't try and 'guess' that you wanted a number in the cell..

Answer (score 2):

Based on data you shown (not tested)

```
Sub colonne_a_ligne()
    With Worksheets("Feuil1")
        .Range("A2").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value), ",")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If all the values are three digits, does this try to convert to number as well?

Comment: I get a syntaxe error. On the first line. No on line 3, but line 1 gets highlited

Comment: See edited code to (hopefully, I’m not by any PC) avoid syntax error

Comment: Same, but what does it mean in vba when it says synthax error ?

Comment: @Jeeped, cannot test it by now. I get the point, though. In that case some formatting could be needed. I’ll wait for any issue of this kind from Ilansky

Comment: @IlanskyNaftali, there was an “Applications” that was to be “Application”. See edited code. Hope this is the last syntax issue

Comment: @DisplayName I still get the same error, but since I'm new to VBA I cannot really understand what I could improve

Comment: Removed a closing parenthesys. See edited answer. Let me know